# How to print a multiplication table using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function prints out a multiplication table (where each number is the result of multiplying the first number of its row by the number at the top of its column).

**Expected output:**

```
1 2 3

2 4 6

3 6 9
```

**Output I am getting from the code:**

```
2 4 6 

3 6 9
```

---

```
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in (start+1,stop):
        for y in range(start,stop+1):
            print(str(x*y), end=" ")
        print()
```

`multiplication_table(1, 3)`

How can I print the first row, What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `for x in range(start, stop):` instead of `for x in range(start + 1, stop):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the below code and it works fine.

```
 def multiplication_table(start, stop):
   for x in range(start,stop+1):
       for y in range(start,stop+1):
           print(str(x*y), end=" ")
       print()
 multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

The mistake in your code was that you did not specify "range" keyword in the first for loop so it only takes the values you specify in the brackets,which is 2 and 3. So now it changed to range so takes from 1 to 4 ( 4 not inclusive ) means only 1,2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in range(start,stop+1):
        for y in range(start,stop+1):
            print(str(x*y), end=" ")
        print()

multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 
2 4 6 
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the `range` in first loop, which ends up only using a list of two numbers.
You also have misplaced the `+1`, which gets you the wrong start and (with range) not enough lines.
Since you second loop works satisfyingly, just use the same pattern for the first loop.

```py
def multiplication_table(start, stop):
    for x in range(start,stop+1):
        for y in range(start,stop+1):
            print(str(x*y), end=" ")
        print()

multiplication_table(1, 3)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 
2 4 6 
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

`for x in (start+1,stop):`

To

`for x in range(start, stop):`

and this will work!